# Hiding a message (to be found) in printed JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been asked by a web company to give them around 30 lines of HTML/javascript code to be used for a wall display. The code would need to be a real piece of valid code that would execute in a modern browser and display a message of around 30 words or less (e.g. a clever/cheeky brand message for the company).

One big `document.write()` statement would do this, but they are looking for something that would conceal the message more. Essentially they are looking to make a visual puzzle that conceals their message from anyone without an intermediate understanding of JS.

To a layperson it should just look like random code.

I'm looking for ideas/suggestions on how to do this. I've tried using automatic javascript minifiers or obfuscators online but these generally output code that is completely unreadable to a human, what I want is for it to *be difficult for a human/coder to read but not impossible*.

Supposing the message to be hidden was:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent
>   quis ipsum ipsum. Donec quis lectus et ante gravida ultricies at."

How could I approach this?

HTML/CSS, JS & JQuery are all allowed.

(Moderators, please move this question to somewhere more appropriate if it's not right for stack overflow)

Comment: This is not an opinion site. Sorry :/

Comment: Where would be better to ask?

Comment: I still cannot understand what do you want.

Comment: you could have many different encoding methods, e.g. encode "lorem" as base64, "ipsum" as base58, "dolor" as a series of svg paths

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 I think the question is pretty open ended but I have articulated what I'm asking for as well as I can. I did say in the question that if this isn't right for stack overflow to move it elsewhere, or tell me where is more appropriate to ask.

Comment: Let's say the message is `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"` what would the encoded form look like (approximately)? Would it be something like `var w = document.write.bind(document); d("Lorem"); d("ipsum"); ...` or something else entirely?

Comment: @vlaz Yes. I was thinking of giving them something along those lines, but was really just looking for people's ideas/suggestions. I know this is an unusual question!

Comment: Yeah, it is unusual. Trouble is I don't know what level of obfuscation is this supposed to be. @Plato's suggestion is also feasible but it won't really produce something readable to a human, unless the human can work out encodings in their head. My suggestion is really, really easy, as long as a person knows what `.bind` does, although you can make alterations by using `.apply/.call` which would require some JS knowledge. You can make it use the `[]` operators to produce something nearly illegible but definitely valid JS code. And so on and so forth.

Comment: For the `[]` thing, I mean something like the output of [this](http://utf-8.jp/public/jjencode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a fun programming challenge, with the added twist of targeting a human code interpreter in addition to be valid HTML/JS/CSS.

One idea would be to show the message in some scrambled or fragmented (readable) form, then display some code that descrambles the message. A simple example:

```
var a = [" consectetur", 
         "dolor", 
         "Lorem ipsum ", 
         " sit amet,"];
return a[2] + a[1] + a[3] + a[0];
```

This could be made more difficult (and challenging to rescramble) by scattering/hiding the relevant string pieces among other (potentially irrelevant code), use conditionals to determine which variables to concatenate, let relevant array indexes be determined by the result of some computation/function call or logical branching, etc ...

An example where the coded message is less obvious (but still readable from code only):

```html
<script id="codeblock">
  
  //JavaScript

  function getHTML(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
  }
  
  var myFavorites = [
    'No Woman No Cry',
    'Exodus',
    'Is This Love',
    'Buffalo Solder',
    'Could You Be Loved'
  ];
  
  var didYouGetTheMessage = (function(letters){
    var x = letters.split(''),
        y = myFavorites,
        z = getHTML('codeblock').split('\/\/')[1];
    x.reverse();
    return [x[17],
            y[2].slice(-4), 
            z.slice(0, 10)]
    .join(' ');
  })('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
  
  //If you still did not get it ...
  console.log(didYouGetTheMessage);
  
</script>
```

I would guess the challenge in pulling this off lies in finding the balance between what is difficult and fun enough to descramble for a human while reading the code, as opposed to what will require too much effort.

Comment: "I Love JavaScript" ?? I like it! Took me a few minutes, the x.reverse() threw me a bit!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to hide the exact message being visible to someone who is viewing the source for the page, you can encrypt the string and store it (hard-coded) in a variable in the script. And you can de-crypt it just when you need to show it. That way someone looking at the source will not see the exact sentence you display if they were to look. However someone reasonably conversant with JavaScript would still be able to see what you are doing programatically to show it.